# how to set back ground color of view to white

Tags: android, background-color

I want to set background color of view to "white" but it is black. How do I do this? I tried it that way:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    View someView = findViewById(R.id.myScreen);

    // Find the root view
    View root = someView.getRootView();

    // Set the color
    root.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.white);
}
```

and main.xml file is...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myScreen" >

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Button" android:text="Play Sound"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you forgot to paste your xml file. please show us your xml file so we could help you.

Answer (score 3):

Simple set `android:background="#ffffff"` in your linearLayout.

Comment: you should accept the answer if you think its helpful for you and upvote too....:)

Answer (score 3):

yes try this `root.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);`

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
root.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

instead of `android.R.color.white`